# How to work with XlsxWriter without saving the file in the disk

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I want to be able to create an excel file from some data I have. Once it is ready, I want to send it using a python telegram bot and get ride of the file.

Ideally, the file will be created from scratch and saved into a variable, and once it is done sent using the python telegram bot module to send the file and end it without saving the file to the disk.

```
import xlsxWriter as xs

workbook = xs.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')

workbook.close()
```

Ok so after the write command I don't see any file created in the folder, but I don't know if the file is there waiting to be closed instead of not existing.

Hoy can I, without saving it, do

```
bot.send_file(my_xlsx,chat_id=1111111)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to not save the file in disk is writing it in a BytesIO object. BytesIO is a buffer, so the excel information is stored in memory:

```
import xlsxwriter as xs
from io import BytesIO

excel_io = BytesIO()

workbook = xs.Workbook(excel_io)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')

workbook.close()
```

You can get the data stored using the method `getvalues()`. More info about BytesIO (and `io` library in general) here:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html
- https://www.journaldev.com/19178/python-io-bytesio-stringio